# ElasticSearch Search geo-points within a circle that was created from a geo-point

Tags: elasticsearch

I've gone through the documentation and searched google but can't find the answer I'm looking for. All i want to do is search points within a circle created from a geo-point

```
GET /pointsinradius/_doc/_search
{
"query": {
"geo_shape": {
  "location": { 
    "shape": { 
      "type":   "circle", 
      "radius": "1km",
      "coordinates": [ 
    -32.360738, 22.56237
      ]
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use geo_distance query

Here is an example

```
GET /my_locations/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "200km",
                    "pin.location" : {
                        "lat" : 40,
                        "lon" : -70
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```